# Initialize a static Pointer results in <undefined value>

Tags: pointers, c++-cli

I have a merely beginners problem with Pointers in managed C++ that gives me headache. I am creating a list of elements and a pointer should show the current element of this list.

The Problem is, when I assign the first element to this list, I want to reference the beginning of this list with my pointer ("varPointer = &firstElem"). But after that, the pointer has no value at all.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
ref class ElementClass
{
public:
    value struct Element
    {
        //some items here ...;
        Element *Next, *Previous;
    };
    ...
}

ref class Queue
{
 public:
      static Element* queue;

      static void AddElem(Element* elem)    {
        //Check, if queue is empty
        if (queue == nullptr) {
            queue = elem;
            queue->Previous = nullptr;
         }
         else {             
            queue->Next = elem;
            elem->Previous = queue;
            queue = elem;           
         }
    }
}
```

The Programs does not throw any error and in the next iteration the list seems still empty. 
Even if I initialize queue explicitly with "static Element* queue = 0" or something the queue-Pointer always has . Initialize with an instance of "Element" is not possible ("a value of type 'interior_ptr' cannot be used to initialize an entity of type 'Element *'). For this I added:

```
...
public:
    static Element^ tmpElem = gcnew Element();
    static Element* queue = &tmpElem;
...
```

The program never uses the else-statement.
I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you all in advance.

(I am familiar with programming in general, but I am new to C++ by the way.)

Comment: *but I am new to C++*  -- And I am new to this "managed C++".  What you posted certainly isn't C++, at least ANSI C++.

Comment: `Element *Next, *Previous;` has unmanaged pointers to data that has likely been allocated managed. Be careful mixing managed and unmanaged pointers. Odds are goods this is what the compiler is warning of.

Comment: in `void AddElem(Element elem)` `elem` is passed by value. This will result in `elem` being a temporary copy of whatever was passed in that will be destroyed on exit from the function. `queue = &elem;` stores a pointer to this temporary copy and will point at invalid memory after the function ends and `elem` is destroyed. Here be dragons.

Comment: I thought structs and classes are always passed by reference?

Comment: Afraid not. In C++ pass by reference must be explicitly invoked. Did some more reading on interior pointers. This may be helpful: [MSDN Page: interior_ptr (C++/CLI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0fh545k.aspx)

Comment: @user4581301: Ok, I have changed the argument type to a pointer.
The function now looks like "static void AddElem(Element* elem) {...}". But nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. This has been educational.

So if you go with a traditional unmanaged pointer

```
Element *Next = nullptr, *Previous = nullptr;
```

and then use pass by value

```
static void AddElem(ElementClass::Element elem) {
    //Check, if queue is empty
    if (queue == nullptr) {
        queue = &elem;
        queue->Previous = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        queue->Next = &elem;
        elem.Previous = queue;
        queue = &elem;
    }
}
```

Kablooey! `elem` is copied on it's way in and will go out of scope and be destroyed on the way back out or be marked for destruction and die by garbage collector at some point in the near future. I'm not sure on this one, but it will be destroyed and very likely before you're done with it. This leaves a bunch pointers to invalid memory. If the program doesn't crash it's not because it worked. It's because you were unlucky and it looks like it worked.

If you go all the way back to C-Style:

```
Element *Next = nullptr, *Previous = nullptr;
```

and then pass in an unmanaged pointer

```
static void AddElem(ElementClass::Element * elem) {
    //Check, if queue is empty
    if (queue == nullptr) {
        queue = elem;
        queue->Previous = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        queue->Next = elem;
        elem->Previous = queue;
        queue = elem;
    }
}
```

It works, but you have to do all of the memory management by hand. No garbage collection.

If you use managed pointers you get managed memory. Great stuff.

```
Element ^Next = nullptr, ^Previous = nullptr;
```

and then

```
static void AddElem(ElementClass::Element elem) {
    //Check, if queue is empty
    if (queue == nullptr) {
        queue = elem;
        queue->Previous = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        queue->Next = elem;
        elem.Previous = queue;
        queue = elem;
    }
}
```

This stores and, as far as I can tell, manages copies of elem, keeping the copies alive. The original elem is unaffected. It has no idea that it was linked because it wasn't. The copy was linked. This is probably all you need. Seeing as `Element` is a value type, this should be all you want.

Otherwise go for end-to-end managed pointers.

```
static void AddElem(ElementClass::Element ^ elem) {
    //Check, if queue is empty
    if (queue == nullptr) {
        queue = elem;
        queue->Previous = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        queue->Next = elem;
        elem->Previous = queue;
        queue = elem;
    }
}
```

Note I didn't change any of the linked list logic. That worked fine.

Comment: Value types (`value struct`) work just like C++ classes in that they are passed by value. The GC doesn't need to be involved with local value type variables. The only time it cleans up value types is when they're part of a reference type (`ref class`) which itself gets collected. This includes boxed values. The value type is just part of the reference type's memory and thus gets cleaned along the way. C++/CLI (*not* managed C++ - this one's legacy) is a special kind of beast: you get the complexity of C++ *plus* the complexity of the CLR, *and* you need to mix the two together.

Comment: That's it. I changed all instances of Element from value type or unmanaged pointer '*' to managed pointers '^' like you've suggested. It works fine now. Apparently I misunderstood managed pointers...
Thank y'all for your help, especially @user4581301, who apparently had a long night researching.